# how to deserialize a custom json to c# object

Tags: java, c#, json, json.net

I use Newtonsoft.json to deserialize this json

```json
{
    "pdf_info": [
        [
         -> this is a object {
           "order_serial_no": "xxxxx",
           // more properties
         },
        -> this is an array ["xxxx", "x"]
        ]
    ]
}
```

In java I can use the following code to achieve this.

```java
JSONArray pdfArray = JSONArray.parseArray(pdf_info);
String pdfArrayOne = pdfArray.getString(0);
JSONArray jsonArray = JSONObject.parseObject(pdfArrayOne, JSONArray.class);
String jsonData = jsonArray.getString(0);
Pdf pdf = JSONObject.parseObject(jsonData, Pdf.class);
```

So, how to deserialize this json with newtonsoft.json

Comment: That's not valid JSON so you can't.

Comment: @Llama I think the '-> this is an...' strings are meant to be comments, not actual content of the json... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (after removing your comments) this would be the c# class of your object
(Copy the json to clipboard -> in Visual Studio 'Edit->paste special->paste json as class'  - [see more on this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/))

```
public class Rootobject
{
  public object[][] pdf_info { get; set; }
}
```

Define this Type and you would be able to deserialize it using:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly -> read the docs. 
Secondly: 
`JObject data = JObject.Parse(jsonText); // deserialize to dict-like object`